# Clicking <span /> with text attribute not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

Selecting an `input` element and filling it with a certain value is straight forward

**Element**

```
<input class='foo' type="test" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." />
```

**Code with click() function**

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      '--incognito'
    ]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('...')
  await page.type('input[name=userName]', 'test@test.com')
  ....
})();
```

I use `input[name=userName]` to select the wanted `HTML` Element.
However, when I try this with `<span />` and the `text` attribute, it's not working.

**Element**

```
<span text="foo" id class="bar" />
```

**Code with click() Function**

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      '--incognito'
    ]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('...')
  await page.type('input[name=userName]', 'test@test.com')
  ....
  await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: load })
  await page.click('span[text=foo]'); // <-- not working
})();
```

Is there a straight forward way to select other elements than `input` by their values attached to their attributes?

Comment: @RandyCasburn you mean this `await page.click('span[text=foo]');`?

Answer (score 0):

The `load` in `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: load })` was not set into `''` which caused the `<span />` not to be there, after the button to log in was clicked...

Answer (score -1):

Not familiar with Puppeteer. But in Vanilla JavaScript you could do:

```
document.querySelector('span[text="foo"]');
```

[After a little digging](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2953), looks like the below is how you could do it in Puppeteer.

```
const spanText = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('span[text="foo"]'));
```

Comment: Your answer is related to this issue it looks like: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3347

Comment: Sure I could do it with Vanilla JS. But when there is a possbility to select `<input />`, then there should be an implemented Method to select other HTML Elements as well...

Comment: @RandyCasburn very similar, I actually found this - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2953 as the OP question is how to **select**. I would agree that your link is how click handler can be bound to the element.